# How to get launchUrl to work in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

When I run my web app, the browser opens and goes to https://localhost:44313/.  This is a not found (404) for me because I have a tenant in all of my routes.  Here is my route pattern `"{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"`.  I edit the URL in my browser to https://localhost:44313/tenant1/ and now I get a page in my web app.

How do I make this happen every time I run the solution?  (I want to set a default tenant.  I thought the launchUrl would allow me to do that.)

I have tried editing my launchSettings.json to add this:

```
...
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44313/tenant1/",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
...
```

But then I run the app and it opens https://localhost:44313/tenant1/ with a 404.  If I edit the URL again to https://localhost:44313/tenant1/tenant1/ (silly) then I get a page.

I don't understand this.  Why is the launchUrl changing the application "base URL" instead of just opening the browser with that URL?

I have Visual Studio 2019 16.5.3 and .NET Core 3.1.201.

Comment: I failed to reproduce the issue as per your description. Generally you can't get the home page when you add the route prefix like `"{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"` . And I am not clear about your tenant feature . Could you share a demo that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I can very easily get the home page by supplying the tenant on the URL in the browser by editing the URL after the browser launches.